# Is there a R Shiny equivalent for .NET session variables?

Tags: .net, r, session, shiny

I am looking for something similar in a Shiny app, that would be similar to .NET's [session variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

What I'm trying to do is to store different variables at the session level, to be used across different functions. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in this link: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html There are per-session objects and also objects across all sessions.

> In this example, each session will have its own variable named
>   startTime, which records the start time for the session:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  startTime <- Sys.time()

  # ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want `startTime` to be referred from other functions (non-reactive) that I source? For an example, using it in the logging functions? I'm trying to get a global variable but only for the current session

Comment: As long as you `source` your code after this line, it will be fine. If you need to assign value to this variable inside reactive content, you need to use `<<-` operator.

Comment: Thanks! just one last question, If I use `<<-` within a reactive content, will it still remain just a session-specific value, without overriding other sessions?

Comment: That is my understanding.

Comment: Thanks I will try that